# ASP.NET Global Class | Global Variables

Tags: asp.net, global-variables

I have a Global.cs within my App_Code.

Here is the variable I have set:

```
static string _conString;

//Connection String
public static string conString
{
    get { return _conString; }
    set { _conString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["BreakersConnectionString"].ToString(); }
}
```

When I use `Global.conString` in my web form code behind it comes up as null.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First,

I believe you should use

```
ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["BreakersConnectionString"].ConnectionString
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.connectionstringsettings.aspx

Second, did you check your web.config to make sure the connection string is there?

Also, you need to return that in your get acessor.

```
get
{
return ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["BreakersConnectionString"].ConnectionString
}
```

Comment: Yes, I edited to add the get. Haven't noticed that when I looked at it.

Answer (score 1):

Since you never set the property, it's always `null`.
In addition, your setter is wrong; when you write `Global.conString = "abc"`, the `"abc"` is never used.

You almost definitely want to make a readonly property without a backing field that simply returns the connection string from the configuration.

Answer (score 1):

why do you need to set the conString? You should update to

```
public static string conString
{
    get { return ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["BreakersConnectionString"].ToString(); }
}
```